# Installing open-cv on Windows 10 with Python 3.5

Tags: python, opencv

I'm having some trouble installing open-cv
I've tried several approaches but only succeeded in installing open-cv by downloading the wheel file from a website which I don't remember and running this command in the command prompt: `pip3 install opencv_python-3.2.0-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl;`

I can now `import cv2` ONLY if I'm on site-packages directory. If I get out of that folder (in CMD of course) I wont be able to import cv2 (getting a "no module found" message).

If i didnt expressed myself well, these are the commands I proceed to run to be able to import cv2 inside "site-packages" directory using CMD:

> python
>
> import cv2

If I try this in another directory, it doesn't work. The same if I create a .py file and try to import cv2

Comment: You need to update your path environment variables.

Comment: @DavidGreydanus Thank you for the answer. How can I do that? I'm new to python and to open-cv. Sorry for my english by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your environment variables.

1. In search, go to the control panel
2. Click the Advanced system settings link.
3. Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the `PYTHONPATH` variable.
4. Click edit, and add the absolute path to your Lib directory

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5 (if I'm not mistaken) and it's files are on AppData\Local\Programs\Python
Besides, there is no PYTHONPATH variable.
I'm not sure, but I guess I've read something on the internet saying that in Python 3 there is no PYTHONPATH variable and it is on sys.conf, something like that, I'm not sure-

Comment: My bad. It should be the parent folder of the site-packages folder. We need to add that to the PYTHONPATH variable so that python can find all of your modules when you're not in that folder.

Comment: Yes, but there is no PYTHONPATH variable on the environment variables, should I create it?

Comment: Under the user environment variable section, is there a PATH variable? If so, add the Lib and scripts folders to that variable.

Comment: Thank you. I had to create PYTHONPATH myself and write the absoulte path of site-packages and it worked out.